# how parse complicated Json array

Tags: android

How to put this in json format.

```
{
    "caller-id": "2434141414",
    "map-id": "2",
    "src": {
        "x": "23",
        "y": "34"
    },
    "dest": {
        "x": "23",
        "y": "34"
    }
}
```

I tried like this :

```
JSONObject src = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject dest = new JSONObject();
        src.put("src", mObjUserPath.get("x1"));
        src.put("src", mObjUserPath.get("y1"));
        dest.put("dest", mObjUserPath.get("x2"));
        dest.put("dest", mObjUserPath.get("y2"));
        json.put("caller-id", Util.getDeviceID(this));
        json.put("map-id", RestClientAsyncTask.mapId);
        json.put("src", src);
        json.put("dest", dest);
```

but is not in format what I expected.Please help
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: when making request on server

Comment: what's exactly is your question. Are you looking to translate this string into Json format. pls explain?

Comment: I have kept wrong header my bad :)

Comment: I have to make request on server by using this json So got confused how to do this

Comment: "How to put this in json format." It is valid json.

Comment: what *Android Custom Canvas* has to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this example and give it a try:

```
{ <br>
    "version": "1.0.0",<br>

    "datastreams": [

        {
            "id": "example",
            "current_value": "333"
        },

        {
            "id": "key",
            "current_value": "value"

        },

        {
            "id": "datastream",
            "current_value": "1337"

        }
    ]
}
```

And

```
    JSONObject Parent = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < datastreamList.size() ; i++)
    {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

        jsonObj.put("id", datastreamList.get(i).GetId());
        jsonObj.put("current_value", datastreamList.get(i).GetCurrentValue());
        array.put(jsonObj);
    }       
    Parent.put("datastreams", array);       
    Parent.put("version", version);
```

**For sending that**

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity( Parent.toString());  
    se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    post.setEntity(se);
    client.execute(post);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to handle this.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {


    JSONObject obj_src = new JSONObject();
    obj_src.put("x", mObjUserPath.get("x1"));
    obj_src.put("y", mObjUserPath.get("y1"));

    JSONObject obj_dest = new JSONObject();
    obj_dest.put("x", mObjUserPath.get("x2"));
    obj_dest.put("y", mObjUserPath.get("y2"));

    json.put("caller-id", "123);
    json.put("map-id", "0"));
    json.put("src", obj_src);
    json.put("dest", obj_dest);
```